# Dispatch receiving undefined as a value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have issue updating the state after a dispatch.

Console logging the result of the `dispatch` shows `Promise pending` and value `undefined` hence, never gets to the store.

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUt5Z.png)

Below is the function that calls the `dispatch` handler.

```
unsetSelected() {
   let some = this.$store.dispatch('user/selectedDevice', null)
   console.log(some)
}


<span class="ellipsis" @click="setSelected(device)">
     <i v-if="selectedDevice && selectedDevice.id == device.id"
        @click="unsetSelected()"
        class="fa fa-times-circle">
     </i>
     <i v-else="" class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
</span>
```

This is the action handler:

```
selectedDevice ({ commit }, data) {
    commit ('SELECTED_DEVICE', data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put alert on the mutation handler and discovered that the code was working as expected only that it was also firing the `dispatch` function above in the DOM.

I have to chain it with `.stop` modifier: `@click.stop="unsetSelected()"`

Answer (score 0):

From Vuex API reference for [dispatch](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch) instance methods:

> Returns a Promise that resolves all triggered action handlers.

So calling `dispatch` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In order to receive data inside component, this promise should be resolved.

You can modify component's method to following:

```
// using async/await
async unsetSelected() {
  try {
    let some = await this.$store.dispatch('user/selectedDevice', null)
    console.log(some)
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}

// using Promise API
unsetSelected() {
  this.$store.dispatch('user/selectedDevice', null)
    .then((some) => {
      console.log(some)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle error
    })
}
```

Also, `selectedDevice` does not return any data, so `some` (or response) from resolved promise will be `undefined` for example code provided in question.

To fix that, store action should have a `return` statement with desired data to return to the component.

Though, following Vuex architecture, it would be suggested to [map state/getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#component-binding-helpers), whose values will be reactively updated after state mutation has been committed.

Comment: All you have suggested I have done but still returns undefined. I have getters setup for the `selectedDevice` still not working. @aBiscuit

Comment: Were you able to resolve the Promise, but it still shows `undefined`? Where do you expect to receive value?

Comment: I want to receive in the store

`export const state = () =>({
    devices: null,
    selectedDevice: null

})`

Then have it inthe component via `computed` property

Comment: `computed: {
            selectedDevice() {
                return this.$store.getters['user/selectedDevice']
            }
        }`

Comment: Please, add `SELECTED_DEVICE` mutation code to the question to verify that everything is being updated.

Comment: `
 SELECTED_DEVICE (state, data) {
        state.selectedDevice = data;
    }
`

Comment: And corresponding `getter` is present in `user` store module? `selectedDevice (state) { return state.selectedDevice }` ?

Comment: `
export const getters = {
    devices: state => state.devices,
    selectedDevice: state => state.selectedDevice,

}

`

Comment: So where exactly do you observe undefined?

Comment: ```async unsetSelected() {
                try {
                    let some = await this.$store.dispatch('user/selectedDevice', null)
                    console.log(some)
                }

                catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }```

Comment: the ```some``` is ```undefined```

Comment: As stated in answer to the question, in this case `some` is undefined, because there is no value returned from `user/selectedDevice` action. Simple adding `return data` to the end of action handler will do the trick. But it doesn't make much sense, since it is the same argument that was passed to the action, so it is already available inside your component.

Comment: Also, since state has been updated as a result of dispatching `user/selectedDevice` (via mutation), you can now access current value via `this.$store.getters['user/selectedDevice']`. Since promise was resolved, getter will return up to date state.

Comment: Thanks @aBiscuit for your time